# I want to add Apache Alias for api (Different users)

Tags: apache-2.4, cors, mod-alias

First of all i'm a  beginner on these issues, sorry for this :) Actually i am a software developer.

I have a project. Many domains connect to Rest Api domain. And all domains locate same server. I want to remove CORS control from api requests.

When i try to use api.example.com subdomain, it still controls CORS.

Last solution on my mind is Apache Alias.

So i want these:

example.com - /home/example/public_html/

api.com - /home/api/public_html/

When url is **example.com**, it will run **/home/example/public_html/** directory. 
When url is **example.com/api/**, it will run **/home/api/public_html/** directory.

How can i do?

(My English may be a little bad. Sorry :/ )

Answer (score 2):

The [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) is used for exactly that purpose.

See for instance in this sample virtual host entry

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.api.example
    ServerAlias api.example
    DocumentRoot  "/home/api/public_html/"
</VirtualHost> 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot  "/home/example/public_html/"
    Alias "/api/"  "/home/api/public_html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Hbruijn . I try this example. But it was an error. My api project with php (Laravel) in My api's public_html. When i set this apache config and i try, i get **500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: Than look at the Apache error log to find out what the exact error is.

Comment: [:error] [pid 31822:tid 139638169626368] [client 1.2.3.4:17700] SoftException in Application.cpp:453: Mismatch between target UID (583) and UID (560) of file "/home/api/public_html/index.php"


[core:error] [pid 31822:tid 139638169626368] [client 1.2.3.4:17700] End of script output before headers: index.php

**This is 2 line error log**

Comment: I think this error because of user permissions. What do you think mate?

Comment: When i try to set all owner and group permissions to example user, example.com/api/ working. But api.com gives 500 error. I cant fixing :/

Comment: can you help me please? :/ @HBruijn